# Is there a way to be notified when an entity in memcache is about to be dropped?

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there a way to know when an entity stored in memcache is about to be dropped? For the purposes of persisting it to a more permanent datastore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jdavidbakr pointed out, no way of being notified.

the best practice for memcache is using ndb if you're in python (as ndb already checks memcache before pushing to the datastore, so it'll hit memcache if memcache has the requested data).

if you're in a language that doesn't have ndb, I would suggest using taskqueues to insert data to the datastore (ie: "push entity to memcache and create a taskqueue to push to datastore").  For retrieve, you first look in memcache and then turn to the datastore if the entity isn't in memcache.  In the event you had to visit datastore to get the data, push it back to memcache.

Answer (score 3):

I'd be very surprised if there is, memcache is designed to be a temporary data store that caches data from another source.  Normally the way memcache would be used is when you need to access the data, memcache is checked first and then if not found the persistent store is checked.  On an update you would either store the updated value in memcache in addition to the persistent store, or delete the memcache value and only store it in the permanent data store, then you would have it get pulled from the permanent store on the next data retrieval call.  With this paradigm, you should always expect that memcache may or may not contain your data.

Comment: why not using task queues as I pointed out?  Easier to respect the 1 minute deadline, no?

Comment: ok I see, I was hoping to use it as a way to minimize hits to the datastore as a cost saving thing for entities that could be updated frequently but will have to think about my design some more.

Comment: @chanakya Well you will in the end hit the datastore less because SOMETIMES the data will be in memcache.  it's just hard to know in advance, so pushing to datastore is a "good practice".  Just remember that IF you find the data in memcache, there is no need to visit the datastore, so you WILL save on these costs